# Python run external program with input and output stream

Tags: python, input, stream, subprocess

I have a FORTRAN program that takes input stream to run. So typically I use "program.exe < Input > Output" command to execute the program. However, I want to run the program in the python asynchronously.

I tried:

```
input = open("Input", 'rb').read()
running_procs = [Popen(['program.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)]

while running_procs:
for proc in running_procs:
    retcode = proc.poll()
    if retcode is not None: # Process finished.
        running_procs.remove(proc)
        break
else: # No process is done, wait a bit and check again.
    proc.stdin.write(input)
    time.sleep(.1)
    continue

# Here, `proc` has finished with return code `retcode`
if retcode != 0:
    """Error handling."""
print(proc.stdout)
```

I dont know if

```
proc.stdin.write(input)
```

This will do the writing input to the input stream.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I figured it out actually there were a lot of post regarding the question that I asked.

```
input = open("Input", 'rb').read()

running_proc = Popen(['program.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = running_proc.communicate(input=input)
outfile = open("outfile.out", "w")
outfile.write(out.decode())
```

Thank you